# Alfresco Activiti missing in Alfresco Community edition?

Tags: alfresco

Just confirming my understanding with other Alfresco users. I believe that Alfresco Activiti plugin, referred @ : http://docs.alfresco.com/activiti/topics/installing-overview.html
is present only in Enterprise version of Alfresco ?

Community version users need to use a external Activiti WorkFlow designer, like the Eclipse Activiti plugin ?

Also, what can one do with the online version of Alfresco Activiti app : [https://activiti.alfresco.com/activiti-app](https://activiti.alfresco.com/activiti-app/#/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes Binita you are right,alfresco activiti engine is only supported in alfresco enterprise version(Activiti UI).

In case of [Alfresco Activiti Online](https://activiti.alfresco.com/activiti-app), I am not too much aware with this but we can create workflow using above as well, including forms. But I will prefer eclipse with Activiti.

Answer (score 3):

Activiti is embedded in both Alfresco Enterprise and Alfresco Community Edition which means you can deploy and run Activiti process definitions in both.

What you are linking to is the standalone Activiti engine commercially supported by Alfresco. Commercial support of standalone Activiti requires a subscription.

If you want to run standalone Activiti unsupported and without any additional Enterprise-only features of Alfresco Activiti, you can download it from activiti.org.

Comment: can you please add more info about https://activiti.alfresco.com/activiti-app,as I am not aware of this.